# Reposition text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How can I change the position of the text to be displayed as I want it, which is highlighted on the image (blue coloured).

[image: The wanted display]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/darekeapp_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/darekeapp_info"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/gdpr_statement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/gdpr_statement"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So it's sort of centered, but just both textviews as a whole are centered, instead of one being right on the middle of the page.

EDIT: Also is it possible to only bold 'GDPR Statement' and not the rest of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the two `AppCompatTextView` in a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation to fit your needs. The `FrameLayout` hee seems useless. Moreover, `gravity` and `layout_gravity` won't work with this type of Layout. You should do this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/darekeapp_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/darekeapp_info"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/gdpr_statement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gdpr_statement"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to bold GDPR, you should use a `<b>GDPRStatement</b>`  in your strings.xml file like this :

```
<string name="gdpr_statement"><b>GDPRStatement</b> - the rest of your text</string>
```

Best